# Check pasted text in input/textarea for non valid charters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input field that i need to check for non valid charters.
I use jQuery `.on('keyup keypress')` function that block all non valid symbols, but when somebody use CTRL+V - all symbols are pasted:(

```
1234567890zxcvbnmasdfghjklqwertyuiopABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"\'- №&
```

String with charters are allowed. How to check with `.onclick()/bind('paste')` if some charters are not allowed.

Thx.

Comment: onclick might not be the best solution here. check on `keyup` or 'keypress' and also `blur` - onblur is triggered when your element lost its focus - that's when you can verify field's value for invalid chars added in any way

Comment: but how to do this?) no metter click or blur. How to check all string that are in input field?

Comment: e.g. `$("#yourFiledId').val()` . create a function which takes string as param and validates it, you can use jquery / js to get input value and pass it to the function (see e.g. in the beginning, that's just 1 possible way to fetch input value)

Comment: i need function that will validate all charters in string, i need help with this:) just like how to take each charter and .indexOf(...) it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion is to sanitize the content on paste, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="the-input" onkeydown="return yourFunctioToGetKeyDown(event)">
```

And a sanitize event:

```
$( "#the-input" ).bind( 'paste',function(){
   setTimeout(function()
   { 
      //get the value of the input text
      var data = $( '#the-input' ).val() ;
      //replace the special characters to '', or use you own regex
      var dataFull = data.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
      //set the new value of the input text without special characters
      $( '#the-input' ).val(dataFull);
   });

});
```

Take a look on the sample https://jsfiddle.net/MarcelKohls/Lg3a9opo/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/[A-Za-z0-9\"\\\'-№&/g` to match any non-wanted characters, replace them with nothing, and check if the string is empty.

Note: I'm not sure if there's a contain method for strings, I need to check.